# What is the maximum local variable a single procedure can declare?

Tags: delphi

Under Delphi, is their any trouble to have many variables declared inside a single procedure? i know that the hint warning will not work with more than 32 variable (at least on XE4, don't know if this is still true on berlin), but is their any other problem i can have ?

ex:

```
procedure xxx;
var A,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z: single;
    A1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,i1,j1,k1,l1,m1,n1,o1,p1,q1,r1,s1,t1,u1,v1,w1,x1,y1,z1: single;
begin
 ...
end;
```

Comment: If you need so many local variables then you are probably doing too much inside the procedure.

Comment: You can exhaust the stack I suppose.

Comment: The parser can have a practical limit on its own. I doubt anyone would try to find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Technically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)? No,

There is no practical limit to the number of local variables.
Local variables live on the stack and are thus limited by the maximum allowed stack size.
On Windows the default is 1 megabyte (although the application can override this default in the PE header).

The following sample illustrates the concept:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

procedure LocalVars;
const
  tooMany = 1024 * 1024 * 1;  //1 MB
var
  i: integer;
  test: array[0..toomany] of byte;
begin  <<-- stack overflow will occur here.
  for i := Low(test) to High(test) do begin
    test[i]:= 1;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    LocalVars
  except on e:exception do
    WriteLn('Fail: '+e.message);
  end;
  WriteLn('done.');
  Readln;
end.
```

The initialization code created by the compiler will create space on the stack for the (oversized) array at the `begin` statement, causing a stack overflow.

You can increase the maximum stack size in the `linking options` (project-> options->linking).
I've never had to resort to this hack and I don't know anyone that has.
The maximum possible stack size is 16 MB.